# Display animation on load ONLY once in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I have an animation that fades in the collection view cell, it is called by CellForRowAtIndexPath.  The issue is that when I do lazy loading and append new items to my array and then call [collectionView reloadData] the CellforRowAtIndexPath method is called again and it basically makes all the cells reanimate.

I have tried using a boolean in PrepareForReuse but PrepareForReuse is called when ReloadData is called.

Is there a way to make something happen when the cell is loaded on the screen but not reloaded?

Comment: It sounds like you are confusing your cells (UI elements) with your items (view model). Cell reuse means you will only ever have as many cells as can be fit on the screen at a time. If you want cells to animate the first time you view an _item_, then the flag should go on your view model items.

Comment: I see what you're saying but I respectfully disagree.  The cell is the View in MVC.  I don't think my model should hold any information about how it was viewed.  What do you think?

Comment: Your domain model shouldn't have view related code. Your view model _can_.

Comment: Do you want the animation to happen _every_ time an item is scrolled on screen? Or just when it becomes visible the first time?

Comment: Every time an item is scrolled